# How to keep Heading together with text?

Tags: page-breaking

I use a very custom style (not mine) and very frequently I get a *heading* 
on the bottom of a page and the next *paragraph* on the top of the next page. Sometimes this paragraph may be a list or similar. The same is true for *listings* and the *listing description*.

- Is there a general way how I can adjust the "badness" of these events?
- Or can I adjust when a section heading would be on the last, say, 3cm of
  a page it should go to the next page?
- Or can I say, if a *listing description" is on the top 3cm of a page
  pull 5 more listing lines from the last page onto this page?

The style I use does not use standard structure tags and environments. But lets call them `section`, `subsection`, `listing` and I will try to migrate them to my lingo.

Answer (score 18):

You need to incorporate the use of the [`needspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace). It provides `\needspace{<length>}` to check whether vertical length `<length>` is available on the page. If not, it issues a `\break` to flush the page content. Otherwise it does nothing (`\relax`).

You could use it in the following way - a very simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{needspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/needspace
...
\begin{document}
...
\needspace{6em}% Require at least 6em on the page
\section{This is a heading of some sort}
Here is the first paragraph after the heading...
\end{document}
```

You could even incorporate this command in the sectional heading command of the style you are using. This way there's no need to specify `\needspace` before the problem (or all) sectional heading.

`needspace` also provides `\Needspace{<length>}`. However, I've always found it sufficient to use `\needspace{<length>}`.

Comment: That sounds perfect for headings. I am still thinking how I can apply this in my listing environment, mainly for the *listing description*.

Comment: This may depend on the definition of your `listing` environment. For example, if the description is separate from the actual `listing` which itself is contained in a `minipage` (say), then you won't be able to extract "a couple of lines". However, it `listing` is typeset as a list (say, `enumerate`), then you can issue your `\needspace` between the last couple of `\item`s, to make sure "things stay together". If this is insufficient, provide more detail about the actual definition of your `listing` environment (or any other environments for that matter).

Comment: @Werneri: I see. I think the specific listing env is very self-made (just a paragraph, not a mini-page nor a enum). I don't like to clutter my listing code with \needspaces. Maybe I will  shift them around manually first ("manual float") and will see how far I get. If that gets to tedious, I will come back to you :-) But a quick glance in the class-file just showed me there is a `\newcommand{\mylistingheading}{#2}` -- well, that sounds promising. Maybe I can tweak that with a `\needspace`

Comment: @Werner: Your answer looks exactly what I need. How can I avoid the need to type `\needspace{6em}` every time?

Comment: @Jeroen: You could try include `\needspace{6em}` as part of the section command. Easiest would be to add `\let\oldsection\section \renewcommand{\section}{\needspace{6em}\oldsection}` to your preamble. It may depend on your document class (which I don't know).

Comment: @Werner: Thanks for your answer. I'm working in an article and your code works perfectly. Now, I'd actually like to keep *every* possible title (part, section, subsection, etc.) grouped with the next alinea. Is using your code for every seperate level the only way to achieve this or is there a shorter solution that adds the `needspace` to all of them at once?

Comment: @Jeroen: Creating an update for each sectional unit is probably the easiest (without knowing your exact setup). Sectional units from `\section` downward (in `book` or `report`) and `\subsection` downward (in `article`) use `\@startsection` to guide the construction/setup of the layout. One could tie into `\@startsection`, but that would exclude `\part`. Lots of things to consider, and therefore my easy solution is to add the `\needspace` on a per-command basis.