# How to force \paragraph to start on a new page

Tags: page-breaking, paragraphs

If

```
\paragraph{abc}
text text text text text text text text text text ... text
```

is on the bottom of page `\paragraph` stays at the bottom while the content is moved to top of the next page. How to force `\paragraph` to also get moved to the top of next page instead of standing alone at the bottom of last page.

Comment: \pagebreak\paragraph{abc}

Comment: Possible duplicate: [How to keep Heading together with text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32111/5764)

Comment: the real question is what else do you have on the page that is causing the heading to separate from the text (since latex already makes it infinitely bad to break after the line with `abc`.) As always you should provide a complete document that shows the problem.

Comment: To people voting that it's a duplicate, note `\paragraph` is an inline heading and the referenced question is about `\section` which is a display heading. the situations are not unconnected, but not the same  either.

Comment: it sounds like you may have `\clubpenalty` set rather low, and no stretch allowed in the space before `\paragraph`.  not nearly enough is known to be able to answer this question in its present form.

Comment: @barbarabeeton actually the external setting of  `\clubpenalty` doesn't matter as `\paragraph` sets it to 10000 locally, so if it breaks there, TeX had run out of options:-)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Please always post complete documents, especially in this case where the problem is in code you have not shown.

LaTeX already makes it an infinitely bad place to break after the heading, so if it does break there, something else on the page made the constraints infeasible, and all options were infinitely bad.

Consider

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textheight{5cm}
\begin{document}

a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f\\g\\h


\paragraph{abc}
text text text text text text text text text text ... text
text text text !!text text text text text text text ... text
text text text text text text text text text text ... text
text text text text text text text text text text ... text

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you push the text down 1 line:

```
\documentclass{article}

\setlength\textheight{5cm}
\begin{document}

a\\b\\c\\d\\e\\f\\g\\h\\i


\paragraph{abc}
text text text text text text text text text text ... text
text text text !!text text text text text text text ... text
text text text text text text text text text text ... text
text text text text text text text text text text ... text

\end{document}
```

TeX does not break between the **abc** heading and the **!!** line, it takes the whole thing over including the heading:

[image]

Note to do this it has to be allowed to stretch the white space enough to account for the line taken over. The stretchy space of the paragraph heading itself and.or between paragraphs should be enough, but it all depends on what class and settings you have used, but haven't revealed.

Answer (score 3):

There are different ways of keeping it together:

- use the `\needspace` command from the `needspace` package
- put your paragraph in a `\vbox` that won't be break
- use the `samepage` package

For the `needspace` command:

```
\usepackage{needspace}

\begin{document}
...
\needspace{5em}
\paragraph{A paragraph}
Some more text

\end{document}
```

For the `\vbox` strategy:

```
\begin{document}
...
\vbox{
\paragraph{A paragraph}
Some more text
}
\end{document}
```

For the `samepage` package:

```
\usepackage{samepage}

\begin{document}
...
\begin{samepage}
\paragraph{A paragraph}
Some more text
\end{samepage}
\end{document}
```