# How to move section label to new page if it is at the end of the page

Tags: sectioning, blank-page

In my report, sometimes, the section label is getting completely at the bottom, or if sometimes not completely, after the section label, there is only one or two lines, like the picture below:

[image]

How do I move the section to a new page if after the section there is less than 5 lines to obtain a new page?

Comment: Like [the previous question you asked](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/186969/5764), this is similar to (and a duplicate of) [How to keep Heading together with text?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32111/5764)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the  `titlesec` package, which has a `nobottomtitles` option (`bottomtitles` is the default).

It defines a `\bottomtitlespace` length, that defaults to `0.2\textheight`. It is the minimal vertical space that must remain at the bottom of the page to allow inserting a sectioning command, and you can change its value with a `renewcommand\bottomtitlespace{some other value}`.

For details, take a look at § 3.3 of the documentation. I think it is better to set `\raggedbottom` in your preamble to prevent white spaces stretching  across pages.