# Memoir: Aligning Section Title With Text and Leaving Number in the Margin

Tags: sectioning, memoir

(possibly related to unanswered [Align section titles in margins properly](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232654/align-section-titles-in-margins-properly))

```
\section{My Section Title}
```

In memoir.cls, I would like the number of the section be set in the margin.  Unfortunately, the `indent` parameter in `@startsection` is not what I want.  It counts where the number is set relative to the left margin.  Thus, if the section number is 1, 10, or 100, the 'My Section Title` is pushed more or left towards the right.  Ideally, the distance between the number and the title itself would stay constant (1em), and the number itself would be flushright against this space.

I read the memoir manual 6.6 again, but the answer is not obvious to me.  I am guessing that `\@hangfrom` and `\sethangfrom` would be used, although this would then apply to all headings, not just section.  Or maybe `\Shook`?

Solutions appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe I've misunderstood what you want, but the `\hangsecnum` command is all you need, I think.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\hangsecnum
\begin{document}
\chapter{A chapter}
\section{A section}
\setcounter{section}{9}
\section{A section}
\setcounter{section}{99}
\section{A section}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]